# Почему Ajax форма при ошибке, возвращается и сообщение, и форму?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Доброго дня!
Есть форма в которой нужно ввести имя. Если ввести более 3 (ограничение как в примере) символов появляется сообщение об ошибке + та же форма. Итого сообщение об ошибке и две одинаковые формы. Подскажите пожалуйста как это вылечить?

**Немного обновил..**

Можно изменить контроллер и добавить следующее

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("NameError");
            }
```

Но такое решение полностью съедает @Html.ValidationSummary() и просто выводит частичное представление с ошибкой, а это дико не удобно если в форму нужно вводить уже две записи, а если их 5.. не будешь ведь вводить в представление ответы на все возможные ошибки + при выводе сообщения форма остается но в данном примере это скорее плюс. Так до сих пор и не понимаю если не использовать NameError почему при @Html.ValidationSummary() дублирует форму, а при успешном выполнении не заменяет форму на сообщение? Что я упустил?

**Контроллер**

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Name(Name name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveName(name);

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView("NameSent");
                }
                return View("NameSent");
            }
                return View();
            }
```

**Представление Name**

```
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxName = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "target",
        HttpMethod = "post"        
    };
}
<div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p id="target"></p>
</div>

<div class="">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Name", ajaxName))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        <div class="">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Модель**

```
public class Name
    {
        public int NameId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Укажите ваше имя")]
        [StringLength(3)] /*Просто для примера*/
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js не подключен ли дважды на странице? Как выглядит частичное представление "NameSent"?

Comment: jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js - подключен один раз. NameSent выглядит очень просто (<h2>Запись добавлена</h2>).

Comment: или и вовсе сделать так return Content("Запись добавлена"); но проблема остается.